# Check the maximum occurence of array in a nested function using ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have the below grammar file for parsing nested functions.

**Grammer:**

```
grammar FunctionTokenizer;

parse     : function* EOF;
function  : ID '(' expr_list? ')';
expr_list : expr (',' expr)*;
expr      : expr subscript | function | STRING | NUMBER | ID;
subscript : '[' expr? ']';

STRING    : '"' ~'"'* '"';
NUMBER    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
ID        : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
SPACES    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Input is failing as it has square bracket.I changed the regex for lexer as:

```
ID        : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9\\[\\]]*;
```

But it is giving error.

**input:**

```
split(mul(add(input["data"][0]["name"][]["node"],input["data"][0]),input["data"][0]["name"][]["node"][]),",")
```

For the above input I am checking which argument has maximum brackets either `[](empty) or [0-9]` square brackets with number neglecting those having single and double quotes like `["1234"]` or `['data']`.

For the above input maximum array is : 3 because argument `input["data"][0]["name"][]["node"][]` is having maximum array.

So, I am trying to implement the visitor pattern implementation but the expression list is not reaching to **visitExpr_list** method.

**Below is the GitHub link for the project:**

https://github.com/VIKRAMAS/CheckMaxArrayInNestedFunction/tree/master

**VisitorImplementation class:**

```
public class FunctionValidateVisitorImpl  extends FunctionTokenizerBaseVisitor<String>  {


    @Override
    public String visitParse(FunctionTokenizerParser.ParseContext ctx) {
        ParseTree name = ctx.getChild(2);
        String visit = visit(name);
        System.err.println("visit1:::::::::::"+visit);
        return visit(name);
    }


    @Override
    public String visitFunction(FunctionTokenizerParser.FunctionContext ctx) {
        ParseTree name = ctx.getChild(2);
        String visit = visit(name);
        System.err.println("visit2:::::::::::"+visit);
        return visit;
    }


    @Override
    public String visitExpr_list(FunctionTokenizerParser.Expr_listContext ctx) {
        String s="";
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i+=2) {
        if(ctx.getChild(i) instanceof FunctionTokenizerParser.Expr_listContext ) {
            String g=visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            System.err.println("visit3:::::::::::if "+i+"    "+g);
            s=s+g;
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("visit4:::::::::::else  "+i+"    "+ctx.getChild(i).getText());
            s=s+ctx.getChild(i).getText();
        }
        }
        return s;
    }


    public String visitSubscript(FunctionTokenizerParser.SubscriptContext ctx) {
        System.err.println("visit5:::::::::::");
        String s="";
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if(ctx.getChild(i) instanceof FunctionTokenizerParser.SubscriptContext) {
            String g=visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            s=s+g;
        }
        else {
            s=s+ctx.getChild(i).getText();
        }
        }
        return s;
    }


    @Override
    public String visitExpr(FunctionTokenizerParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        System.err.println("visit6:::::::::::");
        String s="";
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if(ctx.getChild(i) instanceof TerminalNodeImpl ) {
                s=s+ctx.getChild(i).getText();
            }
            else {
                String g=visit(ctx.getChild(i));

                s=s+g;
            }
        }

        return s;
    }



}
```

**Test class:**

```
public class FunctionValidate {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String input = "mul(add(input[\"data\"][0][\"name\"][][\"node\"],input[\"data\"][0]),input[\"data\"][0][\"name\"][][\"node\"][])";
            ANTLRInputStream str = new ANTLRInputStream(input);
            FunctionTokenizerLexer lexer = new FunctionTokenizerLexer(str);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            FunctionTokenizerParser parser = new FunctionTokenizerParser(tokens);
            parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener 
            parser.addErrorListener(new VerboseListener());
             FunctionContext tree = parser.function();
            FunctionValidateVisitorImpl visitor = new FunctionValidateVisitorImpl();
            visitor.visit(tree);
            System.out.println("-->"+tree.toStringTree( parser ));
            AST ast=new AST(tree);
            System.out.println( "Improved ParseTree:\n" + ast.toString() );
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Antlr AST");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            TreeViewer viewr = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
            parser.getRuleNames()),tree);
            viewr.setScale(1.5);
            panel.add(viewr);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(500,500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }



}
```

[image]

The visitor implimentation is working for one argument but if I pass multiple arguments it is failing.
input:

```
split(rrr(test(input[\"data\"][0]),input[\"data\"]),input[\"data\"])[]
```

ouput:

```
visit4:::::::::::else  0    rrr(test(input["data"][0]),input["data"])
visit4:::::::::::else  2    input["data"]
visit2:::::::::::rrr(test(input["data"][0]),input["data"])input["data"]
```

After expression list method, directly else loop is executing but it should call visit method. Instance of expression list condition is failing so, the method call is directly reaching to else.

Answer (score 2):

For input like `bar["foo"]`, `["foo"]` is not something you want to glue to your `bar` in your lexer. This is something the parser should recognise as an expression.

How about something like this:

```
expr      : expr subscript | function | STRING | NUMBER | ID;
subscript : '[' expr? ']';
```

This would also match `foo()[42]`. If you only want to match identifiers preceded by `subscript`, change `expr subscript` to `ID subscript`.

Comment: Thank you!! , I used the above grammar but in visitExpr method I have to get arguments like input["data"][0]["name"][]["node"] etc.. but it is coming as individual like input , data ,0 , name like this. But as it is a whole argument I want as it is is there any way by changing grammar for this requirement.

Comment: Try something yourself first please. Your entire grammar is copy pasted from SO. It should not be too hard to adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: I have updated the question, grammar is working but in visitor implementation I am stuck, from an expression list method I am using instance of to check whether it need to call the method again or just it has to get result. Every time in case of nested function as input else condition is executing in expression list method.